# Upload file to online storage/google drive/anything, without any prompt?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, google-api-nodejs-client

what I'm trying to do is a website for a photography contest.

I'm using Node.js, Express, MongoDB and Mongoose. I've already managed to allow users to register using MongoDB.

What I am missing now is the space to store the photographs (weight ranging from 5mb to 50mb), and I am looking for a preferably free method of doing this.

I thought of an upload to Google Drive via the API (due to the free 15gb) but I want something that is automatic, I don't want the user to enter credentials or anything else, I want the server to take care of everything by sending only a confirmation that everything went well. From what I understand through the Google API it would always be a question of requesting an authorization and access to Google, which I do not want.

I don't know if I misunderstood and if there is a way to do it through Google in the way I mean but, if there wasn't, any online storage would be fine.

Sorry for poor english. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For what you're trying to do, I think Firebase Storage may be the best fit:
https://firebase.google.com/pricing

You 10 GB free storage, and it's probably the easiest way to do it.  Here's some stuff to get started:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage

Best of luck!